# Get the calling Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the class calling a function in JavaScript?

For example:

```
function Foo(){
this.alertCaller = alertCaller;
}
function Bar(){
this.alertCaller = alertCaller;
}

function alertCaller(){
    alert(*calling object*);
}
```

When calling the Foo().alertCaller() i want to output the class Foo() and when calling Bar().alertCaller() I want to outbut Bar(). Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: `caller...` but its invalid in strict mode.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that is there no workaround?

Comment: @kei No, I'm trying to do a different thing here.

Comment: Since when does JavaScript have classes? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
function alertCaller(){
    alert(this.constructor);
}
```

Comment: That will show the current objects class not the caller's

Answer (score 2):

### You really should use strict mode

[What is strict mode ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

I recommend you not to do what you want to do.

There is probably a better design answering to your needs.

---

### If you still want to get the caller

This is what you'd use if you haven't **strict mode** enabled

```
function alertCaller(){
    alert(arguments.callee.caller);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you ..

```
function Foo(){
    this.alertCaller = alertCaller;
}
function Bar(){
    this.alertCaller = alertCaller;
}
Foo.prototype.alertCaller = function() { alert('Foo'); }
Bar.prototype.alertCaller = function() { alert('Bar'); }
foo = new Foo();
foo.alertCaller(); 
Bar= new Foo();
Bar.alertCaller();
```

Comment: This is also a good method for passing variables to certain functions only! Thank you!